# How can this become x = -9?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a beginner still practicing a lot. 
I think math is fun but a bit hard.

I would like to know how this is solved:

$$\frac{x+3}2 = \frac{x-3}4$$

Solution:

$x = -9$

How? What are the exact steps here, I cannot seem to figure this one out. As I said, I am still practicing a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you can replace the solution and check if it works. Then, if you dont know the solution, you can multiply both sides of the equality to get something simpler (for example with $4$) and then you can add or remove something to each side to have $x$ only on one side.

Comment: $$\frac{x+3}2=\frac{x-3}4\overset{\rm BS\times 4}\implies 2(x+3)=x-3\implies 2x+6=x-3\implies x=-9$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{x+3}2=\frac{x-3}4\iff 4(x+3)=2(x-3)\iff4x-2x=-6-12$$

Alternatively,  $$\frac{x+3}2=\frac{x-3}4=\frac{x+3-(x-3)}{2-4}=-3\text{( Subtrahendo )}$$

$$\iff x+3=2\cdot(-3)\text{  or } x-3=4\cdot(-3)$$

Comment: EDIT: I see that now. "What happens with the denominators? I cannot seem to follow that."

Comment: @JohnSmith, have you heard of cross multiplication $$\frac ab=\frac cd\iff ad=bc$$   if $bd\ne0$

Comment: Yes! I have, I just didn't seem to remember that.

Comment: @JohnSmith, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo or http://www.icai.org/resource_file/16808Ratio-Proportion.pdf should be helpful for you

Comment: The first example above was easy to follow, while the second one which outputs "-3" seems a bit tough to follow, I cannot understand how it outputs "-3".

Comment: @JohnSmith, $$\frac{x+3-(x-3)}{2-4}=\frac6{-2}=?$$

Comment: (x+3)-(x-3), removing the parentheses on the last one -(x-3) = - x + 3, as the rule says, something negative in front of an parentheses changes the sign inside the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, so I was interpreting this correctly!

Comment: Seems like I am still not sure on this one, what happens with the minus sign in the middle. The one between x + 3 - (x-3)?

Comment: @JohnSmith, we have $$x+3-(x-3)=3+3=6$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides with 4. Do you know how to multiply with brackerts? Can you now rearrange this equation to $x= \text{something}$

Comment: Although I know considering OP's level this won't help, I have a huge urge to use componendo dividendo. The simulataneous presence of $x+3$ and $x-3$ is too delicious to pass up. :D

Comment: @Sabyasachi Componendo and dividendo was the first thing I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+3}{2} = $$$$\frac{2(x+3)}{4} = \frac{x-3}{4}$$

Because the $4$ in the denominator is common on both sides, set the numerators equal to each other:

$$2(x+3) = x-3$$

Distribute the left side:

$$2x + 6 = x -  3 $$

After subtracting an $x$ and subtracting a $6$ to each side:

$$ x + 6 = -3 $$

$$ x = -9 $$